# Can I find pre-rebase commits?

Tags: git, rebase

I had a couple of commits that I squashed into a single changeset onto a review branch.  I was under the impression that `rebase` didn't remove the old commits but I can't find them now.  My plan was to keep all my original commits on my `verbose` branch but squash to a single commit for review.  Is there a way to find the old commits?  I'd like to see which changes were done in which commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ORIG_HEAD` label will point to the HEAD from before the rebase.
Look at its `git log`.

You can also look at `git reflog` for a more interesting log.

Comment: `git reflog` gave me what I wanted.  Thanks.